# Windows 7 SSD hidden after Diskpart clean

Tags: windows-7, ssd, cmd.exe, diskpart

I've just used the diskpart in CMD to clean my new SSD, but after this it suddenly disappeared. I can still see it in diskpart, but I cannot see it as a drive under Windoes 7 "computer" in the start menu...

Does anyone know how to make is visible again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have the default setting, "**Hide empty drives in the Computer folder**", set. You can remove this by opening **My Computer** and selecting **Organize**, **Folder and Search Options**. A dialog will appear named, "**Folder Options**", select the "**View**" tab and remove the check mark next to "**Hide empty drives in the Computer folder**". I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello. I've just done that, but is is still hidden... Have you got anything else I can try? :)

Comment: Can you see it in "Computer Management" under "Disk Management"? You can get to this by right-clicking "My Computer" and selecting "Manage".

Comment: Your existing hard drives should come up with blue or green barred boxes, and there should be some information on each. Your SSD will most likely have a box with a black bar extending the full length, denoting unallocated space. Use Disk management to initialize the new SSD. It should then appear in "My Computer."

Comment: Yes I can see it in Disk Management. How do i initialize it?

Comment: By right-click the drive (with black bar at the top) and selecting "New Simple Volume...". A dialog will appear and default through to the end.

Comment: Great. Have a great day.